# Is there a way to get line number and function name in Swift language?

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, we could use the `__LINE__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macros.  These are not exposed in the Swift language.  Is there another way to get similar information in Swift?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The [Swift Language Reference defines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID390) a few "special literals" that offer this behavior:

| Literal | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #file | String | The name of the file in which it appears. |
| #line | Int | The line number on which it appears. |
| #column | Int | The column number in which it begins. |
| #function | String | The name of the declaration in which it appears. |

Answer (score 160):

| Literal | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #file | String | The path to the file in which it appears. |
| #fileID | String | The name of the file and module in which it appears. |
| #filePath | String | The path to the file in which it appears. |
| #line | Int | The line number on which it appears. |
| #column | Int | The column number in which it begins. |
| #function | String | The name of the declaration in which it appears. |
| #dsohandle | UnsafeRawPointer | The dynamic shared object (DSO) handle in use where it appears. |

[See documentation for more information](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID390)

Example:

```swift
print("Function: \(#function), line: \(#line)")
```

With default values in parameters you can also create a function:

```swift
public func track(_ message: String, file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line ) { 
    print("\(message) called from \(function) \(file):\(line)") 
}
```

which can be used like this

```swift
track("enters app")
```

Comment: Swift 2.2 changes are now released and should be the new approved answer :)

Comment: `#` is happening in 2.2.

Comment: #namespace is not a identifier.

Comment: Why have all of those parameters? you wouldn't want to actually change them right?

Comment: Yep, you would only use them to capture call site information like file and line number. So normal usage would be `track("enters app")` without specifying the others.

Comment: Starting Swift 5.8, the #file magic identifier is used to get the format Module/Filename, e.g. MyApp/ContentView.swift.
Previously, #file contained the whole path to the Swift file, e.g. /Users/xyz/Desktop/MyExperiment/MyExperiment/ContentView.swift, which is unnecessarily long.
Currently the newly introduced behavior is not enabled by default. To enable the new #file behavior you should add -enable-upcoming-feature ConciseMagicFile to Other Swift Flags in Xcode.
If you’d like to have the old behavior after this flag is enabled, you can use #filePath instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can get just the file name this way

### Swift 5

```
let errorLocation =  (#file as NSString).lastPathComponent
print(errorLocation)
```

or get with separator from last component

```
let errorLocation = filePath.components(separatedBy: "/").last!
print(errorLocation)
```

### Output

```
ViewController.swift
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get call-site position of a function, you need to pass filename and line as a default parameters.

**Trace.swift**

```
func trace(_ msg: String, file: String = #fileID, line: Int = #line) {
    let pos = "\(file.split(on: "/").last!):\(line)"
    print("\(pos): \(msg))
}
```

**Foo.swift**

```
func bar() {
    trace("baz!")
}
```

**Output**

```
Foo.swift:8: baz!
```