# How to get filename and line-number in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

In [Swift](https://swift.org/), we can use [Special literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103478/4370279) to get fileName, methodName, lineNumber etc dynamically.

[image]

**Is there similar functionality available in javascript to get fileName / methodName / lineNumber etc dynamically ?**

Comment: In what environment?  You [can do so in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201475/node-js-getting-current-filename), but for security reasons I don't believe the browser affords any such nicety.

Comment: Is it possible in `react-native` environement ? @AlexanderNied

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

no

You can get the name of a function in es6 with `function.name`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name but that's about it.

You could return these values from native code to js, but that would tell you about the swift file, not the js file.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the response.